# How to apply a nested for loop on a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe in R that has 3 categories:  Race, Horse, Predicted Rating.  Pred rating is the output of a linear regression model.  I'd like to use something like the following pseudo-code to run monte carlo simulation on the results of my regression:

```
for each race
    sim = matrix(NA, nrow = 100,000, ncol = length(horses))
    for each horse
        sim[, j] = monteCarlo(predicted value)
for each row in sim
    Results = which.max()
```

I don't think I'm using which.max() correctly, but I can read about it and figure that part out.  What I'm primarily concerned with is how to actually loop through my data.  For instance, if there are 8 horses in a race, that race will have 8 rows in my dataframe, so for each race doesn't really make sense.  Also, a race is just a character value, not an object that contains a list of horses.  So how do I access the horses that correspond to my race?  Here's an example of data:

### Race  |  Horse  |  PR

### 1|1|54

### 1|2|45

### 1|3|49

### 2|1|36

### 2|2|50

### 2|3|47

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about how to implement the `for` loops, here is one possibility

```
races <- unique( myData$Race)
horses <- unique(myData$Horse)

for(race in races){
    sim = matrix(NA, nrow = 100,000, ncol = length(horses))
    for(horse in horses)
        sim[, j] = monteCarlo(predicted value)
}
for(i in seq(nrow(sim)))
    Results = which.max()
```